# RHEL + how to prevent OS disk - sda to change after reboot

Tags: linux, redhat, hard-drive, kernel, grub

We installed RHEL 7.9 version on physical machine., when `sda` device was the OS.

The machine has the following disks.

```
sda - OS disk
sdb - data disk
sdc - data disk
```

After reboot OS disk device changed to `sdc` as the following and `sda` became as part of data disk.

```
sdc                  8:32   0 558.4G  0 disk
├─sdc1               8:33   0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sdc2               8:34   0 557.9G  0 part
  ├─VG-VOL_root   253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VG-VOL_swap   253:1    0    16G  0 lvm
  ├─VG-VOL_var    253:2    0   200G  0 lvm  /var
```

We assume on some next reboots `sdc` maybe will change again to `sda` as it should be?

But how to prevent `sda` disk to change to another device, after reboot ?

According to red-hat doc they recommended to set the following:

> users can modify kernel boot parameters by appending "scsi_mod.scan=sync" in the /etc/sysconfig/grub file to get more consistent disk letter
> It will not guarantee consistent device names in all cases. This option should be used with caution as it slows down disk discovery procedure and thus whole boot process.

But is this configuration to set `scsi_mod.scan=sync` in  `/etc/sysconfig/grub`  is really helps?

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG/VOL_root rd.lvm.lv=VG/lv_swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
scsi_mod.scan=sync            <---------------
```

What are the other options that we can to do in order to avoid `sda` disk device to change after reboot?

Some other useful details from the server

```
 ls -ltr /dev/disk/by-id  | grep sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 11:43 wwn-0x6588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 11:43 scsi-36588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 11:43 wwn-0x6588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74-part2 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 11:43 scsi-36588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74-part2 -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 11:43 lvm-pv-uuid-2Ee6HA-9vVx-bUVq-noyG-U0Nq-AVMz-oI56ji -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 11:43 wwn-0x6588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 11:43 scsi-36588a5a0ef7f4d0023880046051e7a74-part1 -> ../../sdc1



cat /etc/fstab | grep boot
UUID=f57f0346-9e6c-429e-b80f-3871334bae35 /boot xfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I don't know the specifics of RHEL(I am a debian user), but  udevadm should be able to address this. There is some info here https://wiki.debian.org/Persistent_disk_names

Comment: its for debian and not sure it fit for RHEL OS versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use persistent identifiers in /etc/fstab for mounting, e.g., replace /dev/sdX with UUID or symlink from /dev/disk/by-id.
2. Optionally, add scsi_mod.scan=sync to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub to slow down disk discovery.
3. Regenerate GRUB configuration: grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.
4. Update initramfs: dracut -f.
5. Reboot and verify disk assignments with /dev/disk/by-id.

Comment: is it ok to append the syntax as the following --> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_root rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lv_swap ipv6.disable=1 rhgb quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync"

Comment: Yes, it is generally okay to append the scsi_mod.scan=sync option to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in the /etc/default/grub file. This option, as you mentioned, can be added to slow down the disk discovery during the boot process.